# Telegram API - account.registerDevice webpush token problem: WEBPUSH_TOKEN_INVALID

Tags: telegram, telegram-api

I'm working with the Telegram API in my application and **I need to handle updates**.

The last line of the [Working with Updates](https://core.telegram.org/api/updates) documentation says that Telegram can send push notifications for updates.

To [subscribe to the push notifications](https://core.telegram.org/api/push-updates), I need call the [`account.registerDevice`](https://core.telegram.org/method/account.registerDevice) method and pass in the `token` in the below format:

```
{
    endpoint: Absolute URL exposed by the push service where the application server can send push messages,
    keys: {
        p256dh: Base64url-encoded P-256 elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman public key
        auth: Base64url-encoded authentication secret
    }
}
```

I have a few question about this data:

- Is `endpoint` the URL in my application that receives updates?
- What is `p256dh` and `auth`?

Answer (score 1):

The keys generated by the commands Semnodime provided don't seem to work. I believe they are too long. You can try using the public key from the online key generator I linked below to see if that was the problem. This could result in a `WEBPUSH_KEY_INVALID` error.

Additionally, make sure to convert the `token` object to a string with `JSON.stringify` if you use node.js:

```js
const token = JSON.stringify({ 
  endpoint: "YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL",
  keys: {
    p256dh,
    auth
  }
})
```

This has worked for me:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

const keyCurve = crypto.createECDH('prime256v1');
keyCurve.generateKeys();

const publicKey = keyCurve.getPublicKey();
const privateKey = keyCurve.getPrivateKey();

const p256dh = publicKey.toString("base64url"); // make sure it's base64url not just base64
const auth = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64url");

// pass to account.registerDevice. I use gram.js
// add a comment below if you have questions.
const registrationInfo = {
  tokenType: 10,
  token: JSON.stringify({ // I was forgetting this and got a WEBPUSH_TOKEN_INVALID error.
    endpoint: "YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL",
    keys: {
      p256dh,
      auth
    }
  }),
  appSandbox: true, // or false
  secret: Buffer.from(""),
  otherUids: [],
  noMuted: false,
}
```

Note that `auth` is just a random [sequence of 16 octets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72370900/8402369) encoded in `base64url` which can be generated with the following:

```js
const auth = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64url");
```

There is a [online key generator](https://www.attheminute.com/vapid-key-generator). If the link is broken, [here is an archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20220525031418/https://www.attheminute.com/vapid-key-generator).

For more info on the key system, check [this](https://web.dev/push-notifications-web-push-protocol/#ecdh-and-hkdf).

More info on [`auth`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8291#:%7E:text=A%20user%20agent%20MUST%20generate%20and%20provide%20a%20hard%2Dto%2Dguess%20sequence%20of%2016%0A%20%20%20octets%20that%20is%20used%20for%20authentication%20of%20push%20messages.%20%20This%20SHOULD%0A%20%20%20be%20generated%20by%20a%20cryptographically%20strong%20random%20number%20generator%0A%20%20%20%5BRFC4086%5D).

Answer (score 0):

> Is `endpoint` the URL in my application that receives updates?

### Yes

> What is `p256dh`?

You have to create your own public key for your endpoint, as the communication is cryptographically secured.

```
# generate a private key for a curve
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out private-key.pem

# generate corresponding public key
openssl ec -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I generated private and public keys as you said. Then I copied content of public key and used it as value of `p256dh` in the token object. But method `account.registerDevice` returns me `WEBPUSH_TOKEN_INVALID` error. A also used `base64 url encoded` value of public key and got same error.

Comment: Can `WEBPUSH_TOKEN_INVALID` error be realted to field `auth`? How can I generate this `auth`(authentication secret) field?