# What is the Base64url-encoded authentication secret that Telegram requires to subscribe to push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, telegram, telegram-api

According to [the Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/api/push-updates), to subscribe to web push notifications, you need to pass the following:

A JSON-encoded object with the following keys:

- `endpoint`: Absolute URL exposed by the push service where the application server can send push messages
- `keys`: P-256 elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman parameters in the following object

  - `p256dh`: Base64url-encoded P-256 elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman public key
  - `auth`: Base64url-encoded authentication secret

What is the last key, `auth` is referring to?

<sub>[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70491805/8402369) is related but doesn't really answer my question.</sub>

---

**EDIT:** [Here is some sample code](https://gist.github.com/marsnebulasoup/3419b353dbab75ffb0b3dfc397ee02a8) to generate the keys per Wizou's solution.

Comment: The link to sample code is dead. Could you replace it?

Comment: @HamidZ Sorry, I'm not actually sure why it disappeared. I don't remember what this was and not sure if I had it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the doc, payloads can also be encrypted using [P-256 Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8291) when using web push.

As per the linked RFC, this encryption requires a public key, and an authentication secret.

In Section 3.2, the RFC specifies that you should generate this secret by providing a hard-to-guess sequence of 16 octets that is used for authentication of push messages.  This SHOULD be generated by a cryptographically strong random number generator [RFC4086].